How to install Git on Heroku?
I need my web app in Heroku to have git installed (I'm on the heroku-24 stack). I'm trying to use heroku-community/apt. I created Aptfile with the following content (found it here):
https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/git-all_2.46.0-0ppa1~ubuntu20.04.1_all.deb

Then, I added the buildpack:
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
=== zerocracy Buildpack URLs

1. heroku-community/apt
2. heroku/ruby

During the deployment, I see this log:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-24 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku-community/apt
remote:        2. heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Apt app detected
remote: -----> Detected Aptfile or Stack changes, flushing cache
remote: -----> Updating APT package index
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease [256 kB]
remote:        Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]
remote:        Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease [126 kB]
remote:        Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages [1,808 kB]
remote:        Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease [126 kB]
remote:        Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages [19.3 MB]
remote:        Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 Packages [594 kB]
remote:        Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Packages [449 kB]
remote:        Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports/universe amd64 Packages [11.5 kB]
remote:        Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/universe amd64 Packages [337 kB]
remote:        Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/main amd64 Packages [404 kB]
remote:        Get:12 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt noble-pgdg InRelease [129 kB]
remote:        Get:13 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt noble-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [476 kB]
remote:        rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb': Permission denied
remote:        Fetched 24.2 MB in 2s (13.3 MB/s)
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote: -----> Fetching https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/git-all_2.46.0-0ppa1~ubuntu20.04.1_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing git-all_2.46.0-0ppa1~ubuntu20.04.1_all.deb
remote: -----> Writing profile script
remote: -----> Rewrite package-config files
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
...

However, git is not available:
+ git --version
sh: 1: git: not found


It seems like there might be a problem with installing Git using the heroku-community/apt buildpack on the Heroku-24 stack. The log shows that the buildpack fetched and tried to install the .deb file for Git, but it doesn't seem to have succeeded, as git is not found. The Aptfile should list the package names directly (git in this case), rather than a URL to a .deb file. The buildpack uses the default package manager for the Heroku stack (which, for heroku-24, is based on Ubuntu) to install the specified packages.

Instead of using a specific .deb file, try installing git using the apt package manager. Update ur Aptfile to:
git

or
git-all

This will install the git package from the (probably Ubuntu) repositories.
Then, try to redeploy your app to Heroku.
Git should be available for u after the deployment.
Note: Make sure you have heroku-community/apt buildpack installed and configured.
If that didn't help:
Try updating everythink.
Try using different packages.
Also note that:
You probably shouldn't use git in heroku anyway.

We can not install git inside Heroku platform. You can only deploy the app via git to Heroku. If you really need to install git inside the app you must need to try something like using infrastructure services like AWS EC2 or AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I use Git inside heroku-20 stack for a number of years, using exactly the algorithm explained above.
